How to recover from a closed channel
I am using aio-pika for my RabbitMQ workers. I ran into a ChannelInvalidStateError exception when the worker wanted to ack the message at the end of its processing but the channel was already closed.
What are the best practices in aio-pika to avoid this issue / recover from it, especially in the scenario of long-running tasks?
Here is mini example of a worker where I simulate this problem
import asyncio
from loguru import logger
import aio_pika as ap
from aio_pika.abc import AbstractIncomingMessage


async def main() -> None:
    logger.info("Starting worker...")

    conn_str = "amqp://rabbit:password@localhost:5672"
    connection = await ap.connect_robust(conn_str, heartbeat=10)
    queue_name = "my_queue"

    async with connection:
        channel = await connection.channel()
        await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        queue = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name, durable=True)
        async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
            async for message in queue_iter:
                try:
                    await process_message(message)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error("Cannot process message")
                    logger.exception(e)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def process_message(message: AbstractIncomingMessage):
    body = message.body.decode()
    logger.info(f"Got message: {body}")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await message.channel.close()  # simulate a channel close
    await message.ack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


